# Create Repeatable HTML Form and Load Info from a JS Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a JS array with info in it.  I want to populate some sort of repeatable object such that I can display all the info in the same way (formatted).  I assumed I would need to use a HTML form, but now can't figure out how to exactly populate it with the information from my JS array.  I want to make this happen on a page load, but for right now I am trying to test it with a button.

```
<html>  
<head>
</head>  
<body>

<script>
var myArray = [
 {
  "title"  : "My First Place",
  "address": "My First Address",
 },
 {
  "title"  : "Treehouse",
  "address": "off in the woods",
 },
 {
  "title"  : "My New Place",
  "address": "Home Sweet Home",
 }
 ];
function addRow() {
  var itm = document.getElementById("infoArea");

  var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);

  for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("repeatafterme").appendChild(cln);
  }
}

</script>
<div id="repeatafterme"></div>
<form name="myform" id="infoArea">
<fieldset>
<legend><label id="myFormID"><output name="title"></output><label></legend>
       <label><output name="address"></output></label>
</fieldset>
</form>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="myButton" VALUE="Press This" onclick="addRow()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itm.cloneNode(true)` must be within the block for and set different id to element new.

To set value of array `title` and `address` should access to children for get elements `out`

```
function addRow() {
var itm = document.getElementById("infoArea");

 for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
   var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
   cln.id = "id" + i;
   var outTitle = cln.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[0];

   outTitle.value = myArray[i].title;

   var outAddress = cln.childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[0];

   outAddress.value = myArray[i].address;


   document.getElementById("repeatafterme").appendChild(cln);
  }
}
```

result: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/sL0v07tt/1/

Comment: There is still the problem of how I actually make the different array elements show up in the form.  I don't actually know what I should use to do that. @CMedina

Comment: yes that is what I am looking for!  Now to just get right of the unpopulated beggining form, but I think I can take it from here.  Thanks again!

Comment: if you could, can you explain the .chileNodes a bit for me, just so I can understand what that part is actually doing?

Comment: `childNodes` returns a list of elements that are within. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes for more information